# Is concurrent synchronization on JPA entity's transient fields necessary?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, concurrency, transient

We know that two threads manipulating the same entity at the same time, will throw an `OptimisticLockException` if all defaults apply. What happens if the field(s) that the threads manipulated, was marked with the annotation `@Transient` or modifier `transient`?

My intuition says that the persistence provider shall not bother one bit what we do with our transient fields and how they are accessed. That further tells me that synchronization mechanisms should be applied to these fields, if we deem that important enough in our application.

However, I have googled all my Java EE books and the JPA 2.0 specification but I cannot find this "issue" addressed. That tells me I must be missing something here and that I'm overly worried??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OptimisticLockException will only be used if there is an @Version field in the entity, and if a transaction tries to save an entity that has been modified by another transaction since the state of the entity has been loaded.

Each transaction has its own instance of each entity it loads. Entities are not thread-safe, and must not be shared by several threads.

Transient fields are indeed ignored completely by JPA. But I don't see how synchronization could change anything, since each thread has its own entity instance. Moreover, in most enterprise applications, multiple JVMs use the same database, so synchronization doesn't help there. Frankly, using transient fields in entities usually show a design problem, and relying on the state of a transient field in an entity to hold state shared by multiple threads is plain wrong. If the state is shared by multiple threads or even processes, it should probably be saved in the database.

Comment: Consider the case where we have a `@Singleton`, also marked with `@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)`. Remote clients, Servlets and other EJB:s all use this singleton.. a lot. The singleton manages a collection of [detached] entities. Every entity has a transient reference to another entity. The relationship is only part of the current application state. In this way, does not threads share the detached entity references? If it was semantically correct, say an entity is a Person chatting with another Person right now, would you still consider that a bad design?

Comment: A detached entity is nothing more than a plain old Java object. The same concurrency rules apply to them as for any other object. It thus doesn't have anything to do with JPA, and whether the attribute is transient or not is irrelevant. If you have such a design, then read about concurrency and thread-safety in general. Don't look for an answer in JPA, because JPA is irrelevant in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet, appreciate it. However, I can't agree that a detached entity is **nothing more** than a POJO. See JPA 2.0 specification, p. 79: "Detached entity instances [..] is no longer guaranteed to be synchronized with the database state". The word was "guaranteed". The book "Pro JPA 2" says on p. 160: "Some vendors might attempt to resolve the relationship" of an detached entity if we access his lazy loading attribute. And the JavaDocs of EntityManager#merge accepts an "entity instance". In essence you're right though. Thought I just point out a couple of nuances for the third party.